# Question on proof that closed interval is compact

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a question on the bolded part of the proof of the following theorem.

> *Theorem.* If $-\infty < a < b < \infty$, then $[a, b]$ is a compact set.
>
> *Proof.* Let $I_1 = [a, b]$ and set $a_1 = a$, $b_1 = b$. Let $\mathcal{G} = \{G_\alpha\}$ be an open cover for $I_1$ and suppose $\mathcal{G}$ has no finite subcover. If both the subintervals $[a_1, (a_1 + b_1)/2]$ and $[(a_1 + b_1)/2, b_1]$ had finite subcovers of $\mathcal{G}$, putting the two finite subcovers together would make a finite subcover of $I_1$, so at least one of the subintervals does not have a finite subcover. Choose the one that doesn't (or if neither doesn't, choose the left most one) and call it $I_2 = [a_2, b_2]$.
>
> We continue by considering $[a_2, (a_2 + b_2)/2]$ and $[(a_2 + b_2)/2, b_2]$ and letting $I_3$ be one of these subintervals of $I_2$ that does not have a finite subcover of $\mathcal{G}$. We continue, getting a sequence $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \ldots.$
>
> Let $x$ be a point in $\cap_i I_i$. Since the length of $I_i$ is $2^{-i + 1}(b - 1)$, there can only be one such point. $x$ is in $I1$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is a cover for $I_1$, so there exists $G_{\alpha_0} \in \mathcal{G}$ such that $x \in G_{\alpha_0}$. **Since $G_{\alpha_0}$ is open, there exists $n$ such that $(x - 2^{-n + 2}(b - a), x + 2^{-n + 2}(b - a)) \subset G_{\alpha_0}$. But $x \in I_n$ and the length of $I_n$ is $2^{-n + 1}(b - a)$, which implies that $I_n \subset G_{\alpha_0}$. Therefore the singleton $\{G_{\alpha_0}\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{G}$ covering $I_n$ a contradiction.**

I don't really follow this last part. Could someone add some more detail/clarify it a bit for me?

**EDIT.** Some specific questions.

1. > Since $G_{\alpha_0}$ is open, there exists $n$ such that $(x - 2^{-n + 2}(b - a), x + 2^{-n + 2}(b - a)) \subset G_{\alpha_0}$.

   Why are we bothering to consider $x \pm 2^{-n + 2}(b - a)$ as opposed to just any old $x \pm \epsilon$?
2. I don't see why $x \in I_n$ (which I buy) and the length of $I_n$ being $2^{-n + 1}$ (which I also buy) implies $I_n \subset G_{\alpha_0}$.
3. How did we conclude that $\{G_{\alpha_0}\}$ is a singleton?
4. And why is $\{G_{\alpha_0}\}$ a finite subcover of $\mathcal{G}$ covering $I_n$?

Comment: $\mathcal{G}$ is a collection of open sets, where the open sets are labeled $G_\alpha$.  One of these open sets is called $G_{\alpha_0}$.  The collection $\{G_{\alpha_0}\}$ consisting of just $G_{\alpha_0}$ alone is, well, a collection consisting of just one open set.  That is, the collection $\{G_{\alpha_0}\}$ is a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give some more details:

- Question 1:

$x\in G_{\alpha_0}$ which is open and hence $x$ is an interior point of $G_{\alpha_0}$.Hence there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset G_{\alpha_0}$.

Hence there must exist by Archimedean Property some $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n})\subset (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset G_{\alpha_0}$.
If you apply Archimedean Property further you can always find $(x-\dfrac{b-a}{2^{n-2}},x+\dfrac{b-a}{2^{n-2}})\subset G_{\alpha_0}$.

Why we choose such an $n$ is to facilitate the proof.

- Question 2:Nested Interval property : If $I_n$ is a descending sequence of a closed intervals with  length $\to 0$  then $\cap I_n=\{\text{singleton}\}$.
- Question 3:

Remember $I_n$'s have been so constructed such that no finite subcover of $G$ covers $I_n$

Are these the details that you are asking for?